# Php custom name to files

Tags: php

How can I make a custom name to the pictures they/I upload, preferably I want them to get numbers as names, and the next picture get the number of the last name +1.

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "../image/DBFilmCover/";

    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    } else {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been      uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
?>
```

I appreciate all the help I can get, if I didn't give enough information, just ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just change `target_file` according to your need:

E.g:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . "custom name";
```

For counting number of files in your directory simply do:

```
$files = scandir($target_dir);
$files_count = count($files)-2; // -2 for ignoring . and ..
```

Now filename would be:

```
$path = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$files_count++;
$filename = $files_count.".".$ext;
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;
```

Comment: I wondered if you could help me with something else too. If I have a database, and I want the name of the photos one submitted to be of the ID of what you added to the database. In my example I have a movie database, where you ad the title of the movie, year of realise and the coverphoto of the movie. What I've been trying to achive is that when you upload this, the picture get the name of the id to what you added to the database

Comment: @TomasBerger sure you can get the id of inserted record from database and use it like this: `$filename = $record_id.".".$ext;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use from following algorithm

1. create txt file and save 0 on that
2. in the uploading process get txt file content and +1 that
3. save file which new name
4. and save new value(+1) to txt file for future.

Also you can save that on database

Answer (score 0):

Because each time the script is run it doesn't know anything about the last time it was run you would need to store the value / number assigned to the previous uploaded image somewhere.

You could store it in a text file or in a database and then increment it by one each time the script is run.

An easier 'hack' might be to use a data/time stamp something like:

```
$filename = 'image_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the next available number for the new image, you might use something as the following:

```
$last_number = 1;
foreach (glob('../image/DBFilmCover/*.{png,jpg,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $name) {
    $number = intval(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME), 10);
    if ($number > $last_number) {
        $last_number = $number;
    }
}
$number++;

$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$target_file = "../image/DBFilmCover/$number.$ext";
```

And then proceed with your `move_uploaded_file` code.

Be aware that the `PATHINFO_FILENAME` option was added in PHP 5.2.0.

Edit: Also be aware that this method (and also methods such as remembering the last filename in a text file or database or using the time stamp as file name) is prone to concurrancy issues if more than one user might upload a file at the same time. To overcome this, you might want to add some random string to the file name as well. But this is not an issue if you are the single user for uploading.